# exclude files & directories containing a $ for rsync copy

Tags: zsh, rsync

I have a win ntfs drive a need to copy from and it contains a ton of files & directories, prefixed with `$` which need to be excluded from the copy. How can I exclude them? I have tried:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/zsh

rsync -a -m --exclude='[$]*' path/to/source/ /path/to/dest/
```

as well as:

`--exclude='[$]*'`

`--exclude='\$*'`

but none seem to work. I'm using zsh but of course have access to all shells.

Comment: Try `--filter=-_\$`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). If `--filter...` doesn't fix it, migrate your post to one of those sites that are better suited for general utility use questions.

Comment: i'll just close and go to super or unix. which has more users?

Comment: @DavidC.Ranking : Shouldn't it be `--exclude '*$*'`, or analoguous in `--filter`? IMO your filter fule would exclude files where the name is **exactly** `$`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
rsync --exclude '*$*'
```

? BTW, your shell does not matter here, because the filename pattern is not evaluated by your shell anyway. For the syntax of patterns in rsync, see the section *INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES* in the rsync *man* page.